# How to explore hardened addresses in bitcoin core descriptor wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, bech32-address, hardened-derivation

I created an blank descriptor wallet and imported a xprv key.

```
importdescriptors '[{ "desc":"wpkh(tpr..../0h/*h)#td3snsa4", "timestamp":"now", "internal": true,"range": [0,5],"active":true}]'
```

I want to get the hardened address of path `m/0h`, but `getnewaddress` reports an error:
￼

```
Error: This wallet has no available keys (code -4).
```

I know `deriveaddresses` can show the hardened address, but it requires the private key to be included in the command.

I have imported the xprv key via the `importdescriptors` method, and I don't carry the xprv in daily use. I think the wallet can show the hardened address, but I don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 2):

You've imported the descriptor with `"internal": true` which means that the descriptor will be used only for change addresses. You cannot retrieve any addresses from it with `getnewaddress` as that only retrieves receiving addresses. You can use `getrawchangeaddress` instead.

If you want to use `getnewaddress`, then either don't specify `internal`, or set it to `false`.

Comment: As you said, I set `"internal":false`, and it works! May I ask you, could I retrieve the addresses before the `next` index in  a descriptor?

Comment: Oh, I find them in address book, Thx~!